# rsync on macOS copies "phantom data" when drive disconnects

Tags: macos, rsync

I'm trying to copy files off of a drive that is failing. It hasn't failed yet :)

Basically it keeps disconnecting every 30 seconds. macOS then automatically remounts it, but Finder is having issues copying files.

So I'm trying to use `rsync -a --progress`, but every time the drive disconnects rsync just "keeps going", and fills the rest of the file with… I dunno, something. I'd assume it'd write zeros, but it's writing actual data according to `hexdump`. In any case, it's not accurate data.

I've been able to reproduce the behavior by rsync'ing from a random SD card. If I pull the card while copying a 4gb file rsync just zips through and writes a full 4GB file, even though that's nonsense.

How do I get rsync to stop copying phantom data when a drive is disconnected??

The problem is that in 2020, macOS ships with a version of rsync from 2006.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsync should exit if the destination drive gets disconnected.  You may need to specify a shorter timeout (in seconds) for this behavior to work properly if the drive is reconnecting quickly.

Something like `rsync -a --progress --timeout 2`

Relevant man info:

```
--timeout=TIMEOUT
       This  option  allows you to set a maximum I/O timeout in seconds. If no data is transferred for the specified time then rsync will exit. The default is 0, which means no timeout.
```

Comment: It doesn't, try it.  `rsync -a --progress external_path local_path`, pull the drive while copying (use something unimportant obviously), rsync will fill the local file with whatever the external file size is, and at a much much faster rate than it was copying at initially

Comment: I did try it, when I remove my sd card in the middle of an rsync copy using the exact command you mentioned, rsync exits with an error.  `rsync: write failed on "/media/tbenz9/4488-170B/data/ConfAvatar/conf_avatar_aec533a0e2fb23033990a1d2821bd225_101": Input/output error (5)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(374) [receiver=3.1.3]`

Comment: wtf?  osx?  rsync version?  I'm on 2.6.9.  That would be much better behavior than what I'm seeing, lol

Comment: Tested with version 3.1.3 on Ubuntu 20.04, but I'm pretty certain my behavior is the expected behavior regardless of OS or rsync version.

Comment: ... 2.6.9 was released in 2006.  I just updated with homebrew and it works.  Apple is shipping 14 year old software that has tons of updates available... gah.  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @zyklus Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and then run `brew install rsync`. The issue is GNU licensing switching from v2 to v3. Read more up on [it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51032585/117259). Rolling your own `rsync` replacement with Homebrew is the way to go. I am on macOS Catalina (10.15.7) and am running rsync version 3.2.3 protocol version 31.